# Android power saving mode blocks broadcast receiver from being processed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

It seems that on some devices, that have Power Saving mode switched on, broadcast receivers are not fired. I have the following code in my broadcast receiver

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long[] pattern = { 0, 700, 400, 1000 };
v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

which is not executed, therefore I make a conclusion that the broadcast receiver is not invoked at all.

Broadcast receiver is composed in the following way:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureTimeMillis, pending);
```

How can I configure my pending intent to be invoked in all cases even in power saving mode?

Comment: +1, very useful observation if its true